# Replace corresponding rows in a column with non-missing corresponding rows from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use all non-missing rows from one column to replace corresponding rows in another column. The data set is from an Excel workbook. The data look like this, say, about 450,000 rows of data across 12 columns.

```
A B
a1 b1
.  b2
.  b3
a4 b4
a5 b5
```

Here I have lots of nonmissing values in B, and I want to use them all to replace corresponding rows in A, regardless of whether the rows in A are missing or not. The data in B also have missing values as well, which I won't use.

Imagine my data in B are updated data, and I want to "update" corresponding rows in A with such information. For any non-missing rows in column B, I want to use them to replace corresponding rows in column A.

I run this code:

```
data['A'][data['B'].notnull()] = data['B'][data['B'].notnull()]
```

There is always a **memory error**, together with the warning:
"***SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame***...".

What's the best way to get around this memory error?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

```
data.A.update(data.B)
```

***demo***

```
data

     A    B
0   a1   b1
1  NaN   b2
2  NaN   b3
3   a4  NaN
4   a5   b5
```

---

```
data.A.update(data.B)
data

    A    B
0  b1   b1
1  b2   b2
2  b3   b3
3  a4  NaN
4  b5   b5
```

***setup***

```
txt = """A B
a1 b1
.  b2
.  b3
a4 .
a5 b5"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, na_values='.')
```

## Old Answer

You can simply use `fillna` if those `.` are truly missing.  The `inplace=True` will update the existing `data`

```
data.A.fillna(data.B, inplace=True)
```

If they are in fact `'.'` then you can use `replace`

```
data.A.replace('.', data.B, inplace=True)

0    a1
1    b2
2    b3
3    a4
4    a5
Name: A, dtype: object

​
```

Comment: What I want to do is to use all non-missing rows from B to replace all corresponding rows (regardless of whether they're missing or not) in A. I ran your code, but the result doesn't seem to be what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code, data.A.update(data.B), did exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy:

```
data.ix[data.B.notnull(), 'A'] = data.ix[data.B.notnull(), 'B']
```

Comment: But it works only for missing rows of A, whereas I want to use all nonmissing rows of B to replace corresponding rows of A, regardless of whether such rows of A are missing or not. The idea is to use nonmissing rows of B as updated data to replace corresponding rows of A, which can be considered outdated data.

Comment: then its normal to have a warning. everything is OK dont worry about that